# permitted_uri_chars in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I am getting en error of "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters" when returning from facebook (using facebook login).

i have set permitted_uri_chars as follows: `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-?=';`

and my url is: `http://www.example/login?state=460f0c9e013ecc3fcbeeas9592ba2cf2e&code=AQDWuAZtPI3UK6vZVL8NL5h0LE28z1jdMRtAbFVjB0IUM7P5WsGFijwlgmzGGZWM37TG0tnCeD8YD-bqCKxilATkyJpiE6UdXhdN0s_s_25S93JRcGyF3inDvLXkadlB6gobStlkguwFlCbaMxV3eWRfo32ExGlN4Mb6OyU2PnWAoRYchG9it0q1KQm3D0N1gSY5_g#_=_`

when i change permitted_uri_chars in config as below:

`$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '';`

i got below error:

> The page you requested was not found.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

`permitted_uri_chars` are the characters that CodeIgniter accepts in your URI. Directly from the block of text above, in `config.php`:

> This lets you specify with a regular expression which characters are
>   permitted | within your URLs.  When someone tries to submit a URL with
>   disallowed | characters they will get a warning message.
>
> Leave blank to allow all characters -- but only if you are insane.

If you want to allow base64 hashes, you'll need to add +=. Change to:

`$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '+=\a-z 0-9~%.:_-';`

Comment: should note that certain characters are rendered as their html equivalents like '$' and that can confuse your script.  also, hashes dont get along with the uri helper.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of http://www.example/login?state=460f0c9e013e.... etc

try

http://www.example/login/?state=460f0c9e013e.... etc

with a slash after the URL. It worked for me